# Best way to configure a Threadpool for a Java RIA client app

Tags: java, concurrency, multithreading, client-server, rich-internet-application

I've a Java client which accesses our server side over HTTP making several small requests to load each new page of data. We maintain a thread pool to handle all non UI processing, so any background client side tasks and any tasks which want to make a connection to the server. I've been looking into some performance issues and I'm not certain we've got our threadpool set up as well as possible. Currently we use a ThreadPoolExecutor with a core pool size of 8, we use a LinkedBlockingQueue for the work queue so the max pool size is ignored. No doubt there's no simple do this certain thing in all situations answer, but are there any best practices. My thinking at the moment is

1) I'll switch to using a SynchronousQueue instead of a LinkedBlockingQueue so the pool can grow to the max pool size figure.
2) I'll set the max pool size to be unlimited.

Basically my current fear is that occasional performance issues on the server side are causing unrelated client side processing to halt due to the upper limit on the thread pool size. My fear with unbounding it is the additional hit on managing those threads on the client, possibly just the better of 2 evils.

Any suggestions, best practices or useful references?
Cheers,
Robin

Comment: A SynchronousQueue is a Blocking Queue (you said you would switch from one to the other)

Comment: ta, I've chnged this to LinkedBlockingQueue (queues up requests when poolSize == corePoolSize) and SynchronousQueue(spins up a new thread as required whilst poolSize < maxPoolSize)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you'd probably be better of limiting the queue size: does your application still behave properly when there are many requests queued (is it acceptable for all task to be queued for a long time, are some more important to others)? What happens if there are still queued tasks left and the user quits the application? If the queue growing very large, is there a chance that the server will catch-up (soon enough) to hide the problem completely from the user?

I'd say create one queue for requests whose response is needed to update the user interface, and keep its queue very small. If this queue gets too big, notify the user.

For real background tasks keep a separate pool, with a longer queue, but not infinite. Define graceful behavior for this pool when it grows or when the user wants to quit but there are tasks left, what should happen?

Comment: This is close to what I've now done, and what I may move towards in future. I've configured a bounded threadpool, with the upper limit based on details in this book http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/. And an unbounded queue. Mainly I want to limit the ability for an individual client to swamp the server, so may even tune down the pool size, but I want also to maintain reasonable responsiveness on the client. Ideally I'll implement your suggestion of 2 threadpools, this fits with suggestions in the book mentioned that a work queue for a specific pool should ideally be homogeneous. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In general, network latencies are easily orders of magnitude higher than anything that can be happening in regards to memory allocation or thread management on the client side.  So, as a general rule, if you are running into a performance bottle neck, look first and foremost to the networking link.

If the issue is that your server simply can not keep up with the requests from the clients, bumping up the threads on the client side is not going to help matters: you'll simply progress from having 8 threads waiting to get a response to more threads waiting (and you may even aggravate the server side issues by increasing its load due to higher number of connections it is managing).

Both of the concurrent queues in JDK are high performers; the choice really boils down to usage semantics.  If you have non-blocking plumbing, then it is more natural to use the non-blocking queue.  IF you don't, then using the blocking queues makes more sense.  (You can always specify Integer.MAX_VALUE as the limit).  If FIFO processing is not a requirement, make sure you do not specify fair ordering as that will entail a substantial performance hit.

Answer (score 1):

As *alphazero* said, if you've got a bottleneck, your number of client side waiting jobs will continue to grow regardless of what approach you use.

The real question is how you want to deal with the bottleneck. Or more correctly, how you want your users to deal with the bottleneck.

If you use an unbounded queue, then you don't get feedback that the bottleneck has occurred. And in some applications, this is fine: if the user is kicking off asynchronous tasks, then there's no need to report a backlog (assuming it eventually clears). However, if the user needs to wait for a response before doing the next client-side task, this is very bad.

If you use `LinkedBlockingQueue.offer()` on a bounded queue, then you'll immediately get a response that says the queue is full, and can take action such as disabling certain application features, popping a dialog, whatever. This will, however, require more work on your part, particularly if requests can be submitted from multiple places. I'd suggest, if you don't have it already, you create a GUI-aware layer over the server queue to provide common behavior.

And, of course, never ever call `LinkedBlockingQueue.put()` from the event thread (unless you don't mind a hung client, that is).

Answer (score 0):

Why not create an unbounded queue, but reject tasks (and maybe even inform the user that the server is busy (app dependent!)) when the queue reaches a certain size? You can then log this event and find out what happened on the server side for the backup to occur, Additionally, unless you are connecting to a multiple remote servers there is probably not much point having more than a couple of threads in the pool, although this does depend on your app and what it does and who it talks to.

Having an unbounded pool is usually dangerous as it generally doesn't degrade gracefully. Better to log the problem, raise an alert, prevent further actions being queued and figure out how to scale the server side, if the problem is there, to prevent this happening again.

Comment: If you reject tasks when the queue reaches a certain size, then your queue is bounded.